# trying to use a recycled bitmap android.graphics.when i convert layout to image in PNG format

Tags: java, android, bitmap, android-bitmap

```
visitingCardDialog.setContentView(R.layout.visitingcardtemplate1);
        Button button = (Button) visitingCardDialog.findViewById(R.id.button2);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                RelativeLayout shareLayout = (RelativeLayout) visitingCardDialog.findViewById(R.id.vistingcard);
                shareLayout.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
                shareLayout.buildDrawingCache();
                Bitmap bm = shareLayout.getDrawingCache();
                ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bytes);
                loadImage(bm)

                visitingCardDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        visitingCardDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
        visitingCardDialog.show();
```

this is my load function
it load Bitmap on photoeditorview
photoeditorview is object of Photoeditorview Class

```
private void loadImage(Bitmap image) {

    phoroEditorView.getSource().setImageBitmap(image);



}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Your question is currently not very clear. Please edit your question and include more information about the issue you are facing (e. g. exceptions and their stacktrace). Also, please reduce your code to a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and have a look at [this help article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me!

```
RelativeLayout shareLayout = (RelativeLayout) visitingCardDialog.findViewById(R.id.vistingcard);
                shareLayout.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
                shareLayout.buildDrawingCache();
                Bitmap bm = shareLayout.getDrawingCache();
                ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bytes);

                try {
                   bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getAssets().open("1024x768.jpg"));
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
                Bitmap decoded = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(out.toByteArray()));

                //Snapshot.CroppedBitmap= Bitmap.createBitmap(shareLayout.getDrawingCache(true));
                loadImage(decoded);


                visitingCardDialog.dismiss();
```